# Why is the 1-dimensional wave equation called like that when it seems to be 2-dimensional?

Tags: waves, spacetime, terminology

The wave equation in one dimension traveling along a string is: 
$$ \frac{∂^2y}{∂x^2} = \frac1{v^2} \frac{∂^2y}{∂t^2} $$
but this equation has 3 variables $x, y,$ and $t$, shouldn't it be in 2 dimensions according to the 2D plane $(x,y)$ the string is free to move up and down (the $y$ component) and right to left (the $x$ component), so why is that the 1 dimension equation of the wave?

I can't think of a wave in 1 dimension, it has an amplitude which is in the $y$-axis and a wavelength in the $x$-axis so how this equation describe waves in 1D?

Comment: it is called 1d since it propagates in one direction , 3d waves travel in 3 directions  and still have an amplitude.

Comment: It's like in the big picture the amplitude isn't considered a new dimension, but what if you zoom in, the wave in a pond, for example, moving in a 2 dimensional plane, would have another dimension which is the height of the wave known as the amplitude, that's my point about why 1d waves are more like 2d

Comment: Well, the question is, do you consider a straight line $y(x) = mx + b$ a two dimensional object? It definitely has $y$ and $x$ components in the 2D plane. Is a straight line two-dimensional then?

Comment: I have edited the title, I hope you don't mind. The previous one was too confrontational, and reducing your chances of getting answers.

Comment: @Ezze This is a very good point, and one that often confuses physicists studying formal geometry. For example, the $n$-sphere is the sphere that is _parametrized by_ $n$ parameters, not the sphere that _lives in_ $n$ spatial dimensions. So the 1-sphere is the circle, despite us usually thinking of circles as 2-dimensional. Likewise, the 2-sphere is the conventional "3D" sphere, and so on. The distinction is important, but is rarely one we have to think about in physics.

Comment: @Ezze if we rotate the 2D plane in way that the $ x $-axis match the function $ y(x) = mx +b $ it would be clear that a straight light isn't a two dimensional object, but in this case we are referring at a sinusoidal wave equation which is a curve function in 2D plane and is two dimensional object. (there is no way rotating the 2D plane could make this function look like a 1D object)

Comment: Renaming the variable 'y' to 'u' might remove some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The 1D wave equation is called like that because it has only one independent space variable, $x$. That's it. The 2D equation has two variables, etc.

You are correct that an oscillating rope sweeps out a 2-dimensional plane; in fact, by moving one end in a circle instead of up and down, you can make it occupy a 3D region. But the equation doesn't care about that: it's just an equation for a function that depends on $x$ and $t$. If you consider the 3D behavior of the rope then you will have more functions, but they will still only depend on $x$ and $t$, so the equation (or equations) will still be 1-dimensional.

To summarize: the dimensionality of the wave equation refers to the number of independent space variables, and not the dimensions of the movement. There are, as far as I know, two good reasons for this:

- Not every wave is a moving rope. For example, we could imagine something like, say, temperature obeying a wave equation in 3D space$^1$. The temperature is not moving in any direction like a rope is, so it doesn't make much sense to assign a physical dimension to it, but it does depend on the three variables $(x,y,z)$, so we'd talk about the 3D wave equation.
- The mathematical properties of the solutions depend mostly on the number of independent variables, and not so much on the number of functions, so it makes more sense to classify the equations by the number of variables and call that the dimension.

---

$^1$I'm not actually sure if there is a situation in which the temperature obeys the wave equation, but this is just an example.

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are an example of a non-matter wave.

Comment: @BillN: Yes, but they are 3D vectors, so my point about ignoring the dimension of the functions would not be as strong. Also they are more abstract, and frequently hard to understand for this very reason.

Comment: And to add another consideration, if the wave is longitudinal, the $y$ variable describes motion parallel to the propagation, $x$, and not a 2nd spatial coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) $\Box y=0$ is satisfied for a scalar field $$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}~\ni~ (\vec{x},t)\quad \stackrel{y}{\mapsto} \quad y(\vec{x},t)  ~\in~ \mathbb{R},$$ with spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function), and with a 1-dimensional target space $\mathbb{R}$, we speak of the wave equation in $n+1$-dimensional spacetime, or equivalently, the wave equation in $n$-dimensional space.